# What is the frequency response of a first-order system of ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory

What is the frequency response of a first-order system of ODEs?  Specifically, given the differential equation:

$$
y'(t) = Ay(t) + x(t)
$$

where $y:[0,\infty]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, what is the solution when

$$
x(t)=\begin{bmatrix}0\\\vdots\\\cos(\omega t)\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix} = \cos(\omega t) b_i?
$$

Essentially, if we have a first-order system of ODEs and we activate a single input with a sine wave of a given frequency, what is the solution?  Normally, the frequency response is worked out for a linear time invariant system of higher order and the solution is just a phase shifted and amplitude scaled version of the sine wave.  I'm interested in what this result looks like for a first-order system rather than a single equation.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you are probably looking for has the form $$y(t)=u\cos(ωt)+v\sin(ωt).$$ Insert into the DE to get the linear system for the vectors $u,v$. Take care of what happens if $iω$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

I use $Y(s)$ and $X(s)$ to denote the Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}\{y(t)\}(s)$ and $\mathcal{L}\{y(t)\}(s)$ respectively. Furthermore, it is worth nothing that for $A(s)=\mathcal{L}\{a(t)\}(s)$ it hold that $\mathcal{L}\{a'(t)\}(s)=s\,A(s)-a(0)$, with $a'(t)$ denoting the derivative of $a(t)$ with respect to time ($t$). Combing this with your original system of first order ODEs yields

$$
s\,Y(s) - y(0) = A\,Y(s) + X(s). \tag{1}
$$

Solving $(1)$ for $Y(s)$ yields

$$
Y(s) = (s\,I - A)^{-1} (X(s) + y(0)). \tag{2}
$$

Often for frequency response analysis it is assumed that $y(0)=0$. And for the steady state frequency response one can substitute in $s=j\,\omega$.

---

This is also related to converting state space models into transfer functions. So when starting with the following state space model

\begin{align}
x'(t) &= A\,x(t) + B\,u(t) \\
y(t) &= C\,x(t) + D\,u(t)
\end{align}

then the corresponding transfer function can be [obtained using](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Representations/SysRepTransformations/TF2SS.html)

$$
G(s) = C\,(s\,I - A)^{-1} B + D.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Your equation (2) matches what I have in the s-domain.  That said, where I'm struggling is with the frequency response given the `x(t)` above.  Essentially, one of the elements in `X(s)` corresponds to the Laplace transform of `cos(\omega t)`, or `s/(s^2+omega^2)`, and the rest are zero.  What I'm unsure of how to compute is the inverse Laplace transform of the result.  Technically, we could write down something in terms of an integral of a matrix exponential, but I believe the result should look something like a scaled, shifted sine wave.  That's what I'm looking for